# How do I find a digital (non-WiFi) baby monitor with an encrypted signal?

Tags: encryption, wireless

What would I look for to see if a digital baby monitor (audio or video, but non-IP/WiFi) has an actual encrypted signal, or at least something to defend against the following threat model?

As I'm not putting the stream on the Internet, my attacker would just be your basic neighborhood creeper pairing another receiver to my unit within range of my house and using the "Talk to Baby!" feature (another anti-feature IMO). This is not the end of the world, but [apparently people do this](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2913356/cybercrime-hacking/2-more-wireless-baby-monitors-hacked-hackers-remotely-spied-on-babies-and-parents.html) and I'd like to avoid it.

I've had a hard time finding any information about this at all. As you can imagine, the marketing pages are worse than useless, just throwing words like "private!" and "secure!" everywhere (and in the worst cases conflating "digital" with "encrypted"). I've seen some with frequency hopping which is better than nothing, but no information about any real encryption.

Comment: wifi would be safer than something an engineered rolled themselves; use a 2nd router not connect to the web if in doubt

Comment: Note that frequency hopping (and other spread spectrum techniques) as done in typical consumer products does not provide security or privacy. It's only useful to reduce the likelihood of interference. Although it can be used to reduce the risk of interception or detection, that puts extreme limitations on the amount of data that can be transmitted, so it's really only useful in military situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a baby monitor which uses Bluetooth version 4.2, as older versions may be using much weaker cryptography. Version 4.2 uses strong encryption with the AES cipher, a block cipher with no known practical attacks against it, in CCM mode in order to ensure data integrity. For key exchange, it uses P-256, a strong ECC algorithm approved by NIST which provides the equivalent of approximately 128 bits of classical security. Note that this may not protect against active attackers who perform a man-in-the-middle attack, depending on what pairing mode is used, but it should protect from passive attacks.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I wish they would actually advertise this stuff on the packaging.